# How to find time difference between two dates using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

How to find time difference between two dates using PHP.

For example i am having two dates:

**start Date : 2010-07-30 00:00:00**

**end Date   : 2010-07-30 00:00:00**

In this case how shall i find the **time difference using PHP**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the date difference between 2 dates using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-date-difference-between-2-dates-using-php)

Comment: But i need like following : 24hrs 3 minutes 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$date1 = $deal_val_n['start_date'];

$date2 = $deal_val_n['end_date'];

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60));

$minuts = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60);

$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60));
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

> But i need like following : 24hrs 3 minutes 5 seconds

If you're using PHP 5.3 or better (which you should be), you can use the built in [DateTime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to produce a [DateInterval](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) which can be [formatted](http://us.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) easily.

```
$time_one = new DateTime('2010-07-29 12:43:54');
$time_two = new DateTime('2010-07-30 01:23:45');
$difference = $time_one->diff($time_two);
echo $difference->format('%h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
```

DateTime was introduced in 5.1, but DateInterval is new to 5.3.

Answer (score 4):

```
$d1 = strtotime('2010-07-30 00:00:00');
$d2 = strtotime('2010-07-30 00:00:02');

$diff = $d2 - $d1;

echo $diff;
```

You will have second in $diff variable

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
<?php
    $date1 = $deal_val_n['start_date'];

    $date2 = $deal_val_n['end_date'];

    $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

    $hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60));

    $minuts = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60);

    $seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60));
    ?>
```