# Add days to a date (PHP)

Tags: php

I am saving dates like so: 2013-11-06 using date function

```
date("Y-m-d")
```

Would like to add three days to the date. Would I need to use strtotime() for this?

Comment: You need to use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+add+days+to+date).

Comment: Almost every question posted by this person could qualify for being off topic with the reason of "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Add days to a date (PHP)

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-22');
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

you may find here more [Date time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

### Update

- [How to find time difference between two dates using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370653/how-to-find-time-difference-between-two-dates-using-php):
  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374053/3471582)
- [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php): [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374053/3471582)

Comment: +1 for using the new OO interface. Works for PHP 5.3 upwards AFAIK.

Comment: @JohannesH. definitely not **new**

Comment: @Phil: Well, newer than date() - and way cleaner. Modern code shouldn't use old interfaces when newer ones are available. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));
```

Comment: Right, this will only work for the current date though. I need to increase older dates saved in variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here, really easy:

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$date_plus_3_days=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 days"));
```

`strtotime` can do lots of other related things: [PHP.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: You have not specified a correct *format* parameter for `date()`. This **will not work**

Comment: @Phil: Oops, thanks, fixed it. My fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this.

```
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$date->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```